# Как правильно работать с if в or конструкции Python?

Tags: python

```
import time
import os
print('Введите сочитание клавиш')
while True:
    a=input()
    if a == 'n' or 'т':
        os.startfile(r"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe")
    elif a == 'v'or'м':
        os.startfile(r"C:\Windows\explorer.exe")
    else:
        print('Неправильно')
```

когда я нажимаю v открывается sublime text

Comment: `if a == 'n' or 'т':` - это условие истинно в двух случаях: когда истинно `if a == 'n'` или истинно `if 'т'`, а не когда истинно `if a == 'n'` или `if a == 'т'`. А подстановка строки в условие вернёт `True` для непустой строки, что у Вас и происходит (т.е. независимо от ввода вообще `if 'т'` даёт `True` и выполняется первая ветка); в `elif`, кстати, та же ошибка допущена

Comment: Тут уже были несколько абсолютно аналогичных по сути вопросов, найдите дубликат кто-нибудь, мне лень

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас после or не указана переменная, которую требуется проверить, но лично я бы, использовал оператор in, он возвращает истину, если элемент присутствует в последовательности, иначе возвращает ложь.

```
import time
import os
print('Введите сочитание клавиш')
while True:
    a=input()
    if a in ('n','т'):
        os.startfile(r"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe")
    elif a in ('v','м'):
        os.startfile(r"C:\Windows\explorer.exe")
    else:
        print('Неправильно')
```

Comment: Небольшое пояснение, почему так, было бы очень кстати

Comment: Вносите уточнения в ответ плиз, кнопка "править"

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
import os


print('Введите сочитание клавиш')
while True:
    a=input()
    if a == 'n' or a == 'т':
        os.startfile(r"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe")
    elif a == 'v' or a == 'м':
        os.startfile(r"C:\Windows\explorer.exe")
    else:
        print('Неправильно')
```

Вы в условиях написали некорректный оператор после `or`