# python не работает or

Tags: python

Написал код, который должен при вводе цифры месяца выдавать ответ, что за месяц. Я мог через кучу if написать, но решил попробовать через `or`, правда не особо понял как работает.
Код ниже - не рабочий, при любом варианте даёт ответ 'зима'.
сам код:

```
a = input()
if a == '12' or '1' or '2':
    print('Зима')
elif a == '3' or '4' or '5':
    print('Весга')
elif a == '6' or '7' or '8':
    print('Лето')
elif a == '9' or '10' or '11':
    print('Осень')
else:
    print('ыыы')
```

Comment: Если хочешь использовать `or`, то надо сравнивать `a` в каждом условии `or`, т.е. `if a == '12' or a == '1' or a == '2':`. Если хочешь короче записать, то можно, например, использовать список или кортеж и проверять, есть ли `a` в нем: `if a in ('12', '1', '2'):` и т.д.

Comment: `a == '12' or '1' or '2'` - это то же самое, что `a == '12' or '1' is True or '2' is True`, т.е. ты проверяешь только, равно ли `a` стрингу `12`, а остальные условия в `or` всегда будут выдавать `True`.

Comment: Этот вопрос задавали уже минимум раз пять, отметьте дубликатом кто-нибудь

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно работать с if в or конструкции Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/972583/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-if-%d0%b2-or-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if a == '12' or a == '1' or a =='2':
print('Зима')
elif a == '3' or a== '4' or a === '5':
print('Весга')
elif a == '6' or a =='7' or a == '8':
print('Лето')
elif a == '9' or a == '10' or a == '11':
print('Осень')
else:
print('ыыы')
```

Думаю, Вы уже поняли)) (а лучшее вообще использовать не str, а int)

Answer (score 3):

В таких случаях лучше использовать `in`:

```
a = input()
if a in ('12', '1', '2'):
    print('Зима')
elif a in ('3', '4', '5'):
    print('Весга')
elif a in ('6', '7', '8'):
    print('Лето')
elif a in ('9', '10', '11'):
    print('Осень')
else:
    print('ыыы')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if a in ['12','1','2']:
    print('Зима')
```

это просто пример дальше сам :))))